# Using Akamai Purge API with rest assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, akamai

Just been handed the task of writing a java method to do an akamai purge.  I've been through the dev docs at akamai, tried to use their community (which seems to allow new members), and things are still quite a jumble.  Other than just pointing me to the Akamai site, can I get some assistance to at least get started?

I have the host (API Base URL), I have the Access Token, and I have the Content Provider Codes.  What else am I missing?

Is there not just a simple REST call that can be made to perform the purge?  Everything I see on the Akamai site says there is, but has no useful, simple examples.  Other questions here, just refer the questioner to the Akamai dev site  where they sited, or their community site where it seems registration no longer works.

So, lets say I have the following:

`Host - https://akab-myhost.purge.akamaapis.net
Access Token - akab-alphanumericstuff-alphanumericstuff
Content Provider Codes - 
                          919191 - www.thisismysite.com.pm1
                          919192 - www.thisismysite.com.pm2`

How do I (using java) make a rest call to purge CPC 919191?

Thanks!
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/docs/index.html ? It gives pretty clear steps on how the REST calls are made. Also i would recommend to reconsider if you really want to purge CP Code? As this will purge everything with that CP Code. Instead i would recommend URL path or extension based Purge.

Also i would recommend to use fast purge API: https://developer.akamai.com/api/purge/ccu-v2/resources.html
Normal CCU takes ~5min to purge, where as fast purge takes less than 5sec to purge.